# Laravel JsonResource foreign table is empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-10, laravel-middleware, laravel-eloquent-resource

I'm a beginner with Laravel and inertia.
I use Laravel 10 with Inertia and react.

When I go to the index page, the field "$this->typeEducation->title" is filled, but when I click edit, the field is empty. I then get the error message: "**Attempt to read property "title" on null**"

The model:

```
class Education extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'education_type_id',
        'is_active',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
    ];

    public function typeEducation() {
        return $this->belongsTo(EducationType::class, 'education_type_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

The resource:

```
class EducationResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            'id' => $this->id,
            'title' => $this->title,
            'type' => $this->typeEducation->title,
            'isActive' => $this->is_active,
            'startDate' => $this->start_date,
            'endDate' => $this->end_date,
            'educationTypes' => EducationTypeResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('educationTypes'))
        ];
    }
}
```

The Controller

```
class EducationController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return Inertia::render('School/Education/EducationIndex', [
            'education' => EducationResource::collection(Education::all())
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     */
    public function edit(Education $education): Response
    {
        $education->load(['typeEducation']);
        return Inertia::render('School/Education/Edit', [
            'education' => new EducationResource($education),
            'educationTypes' => EducationTypeResource::collection(EducationType::all())
        ]);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!
In the controller I first need to retrieve the record:

```php
class EducationController extends Controller {
    public function index(): Response {
        return Inertia::render('School/Education/EducationIndex', [
            'education' => EducationResource::collection(Education::all())
        ]);
    }

    public function edit(string $id): Response {
        $education = Education::findOrFail($id);
        $education->load(['typeEducation']);
        return Inertia::render('School/Education/Edit', [
            'education' => new EducationResource($education),
            'educationTypes' => EducationTypeResource::collection(EducationType::all())
        ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check that the `education_type_id` in the `Education` model corresponds to an existing `id` in the `EducationType` model in your database. May be the foreign key is not set correctly.

Comment: It corresponds. It works on the index page, but not when I go to the edit page. They use the same resource